# Conditional inner join statement (VBA/SQL) to generate multiple values

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I'm quite new to VBA/SQL and I'm trying to execute a conditional inner join.

I have two tables with a column in common ("CRM" and "CodeCRM") and I would like to obtain an email adress from table2 ("Desks") when something is triggered (CodeBlocage = 101) in table1 ("Flux") in order to add it to an automatic email.

```
Dim StrDestinataire As String
Select Case Strtable
   Case "Flux", "GAFIJOUR"

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Y As String
    Dim sSql As String

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection


    sSql = "Select AddMailCRM from Desks Inner Join Flux on Desks.CODECRM = Flux.CRM WHERE Flux.CODEBLOCAGE = '101'"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(sSql)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        Y = rs.Fields("AddMailCRM").Value
    End If


    StrDestinataire =  Y

    cn.Close
```

Everything works great except that it should be returning more than one value for the email adress. Any leads?

Thank you

Comment: Why not just add a where clause? `Select email from table2 Inner Join table1 on table2.Crm = table1.Crm WHERE table1.Code = 1` ?

Comment: Now my problem seems to be on the "Select":                                    Select Case Strtable
Case "Flux"                                                                                                 Select email from table2 Inner Join table1 on table2.Crm = table1.Crm WHERE table1.Code = 1                                                                                                                  End Select

Comment: @Etienne can you edit your original question to reflect this please?  It's unclear what you're asking now

Comment: Sure. I'm not used to the Platform yet, I'm editing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three keywords that may cause confusion:

**SELECT in sql**

SELECT determines the columns in the resulting recordset. If your sql statement is `SELECT Name, Number FROM Employees`, the SELECT part tells you that the resulting recordset will have two columns named Name and Number.

**Select Case in VBA**

Select Case is a programming construct for conditionals. You'd use it when you don't want to use a bunch of If..ElseIf..Else statements, but anything you can do with If you can do with Select Case.

```
Select Case A
    Case "Flux"
        Execute these VBA statements when the variable A = Flux
    Case "Capacitor"
        Execute these statements when A = Capacitor
    Case Else
        Execute these statements when A is neither Flux nor Capacitor
End Select
```

**CASE in sql**

The CASE keyword in sql is like Select Case in VBA, but it's used in the field list of a SELECT sql statement (for one).

```
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN Number = 1 THEN 'One' ELSE 'Two' END MyNum FROM Employees
```

If you execute this recordset, you get two columns (Name, MyNum). The MyNum field will contains the text `One` when Number is 1 for that record and the text `Two` if Number is anything but 1.

**Recordsets**

You have both Excel and Access tags, so I'm going to assume you're using ADO in either one of those.  Your statement

```
Y = Select email from table2 Inner Join table1 on table2.Crm = table1.Crm WHERE table1.Code = 1
```

Doesn't do anything - it wouldn't compile. Let's assume you want a variable, `Y`, to contain the email that would be returned if you executed that sql statement.

```
Sub GetEmail()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Y As String
    Dim sSql As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "MyConnectionStringGoesHere"

    sSql = "Select email from table2 Inner Join table1 on table2.Crm = table1.Crm WHERE table1.Code = 1"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(sSql)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        Y = rs.Fields("email").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

In this case I have to create a recordset and execute that recordset for a certain connection. Presumably the join and the WHERE clause ensures that it will only return one record. But if it returns more, this example will only use the email from the first record.

Before I grab the Value of the email field, I make sure that the recordset returned at least one record. If it's at the beginning of the file (BOF) and at the end of the file (EOF) at the same time, that means there are no records in the recordset.

Comment: Dick thank you so much for taking the time. I just read a couple of posts about recordsets and I'm getting there. However, what is my connection string there? If you could provide me an example that would be great.

Comment: The way I get connection strings: In Excel - Data - Get External Data - and create an external data table point at the database you want. Then go to the Immediate Window (Alt+F11, Ctrl+G) and type `?activecell.ListObject.QueryTable.Connection` and you'll get something like this `OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True...` except a bit longer. The first part is OLEDB or ODBC - just remove that part and you have a connection string.

Comment: Thank you Dick! You mentionned "Presumably the join and the WHERE clause ensures that it will only return one record. But if it returns more, this example will only use the email from the first record.". How could I return multiple email adresses?

Comment: Instead of `rs.Fields("email").Value` you can use `rs.GetString` which will return a string of all the emails from all the records.

Comment: Y = rs.GetString("AddMailCRM").Value returns the error "invalid qualifier"

Comment: The syntax is `Y = rs.GetString`. The `GetString` method returns the entire recordset as a big, long string. So you don't specify the column or use a Value property. Because it returns the entire recordset, you'd only use it when the recordset contains only the data you want.

Comment: Great, thank you Dick. The last detail bothering me now is that I get all the email adresses of the recordset but some of them are in double. How could I delete the doubles?

Comment: Change you SQL statement to `SELECT DISTINCT email FROM...` to only get unique emails.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
Dim StrDestinataire As String
Select Case Strtable
   Case "Flux", "GAFIJOUR"

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Y As String
    Dim sSql As String

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection


    sSql = "Select AddMailCRM from Desks Inner Join Flux on Desks.CODECRM = Flux.CRM WHERE Flux.CODEBLOCAGE = '101'"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(sSql)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        Y = rs.Fields("AddMailCRM").Value
    End If


    StrDestinataire =  Y

    cn.Close
```